# IO domain registry

Tags: dns, io, registration

I am looking to register a .io domain, however none of my usual registrars can do it for me.

Where can I register a .io domain? Can anybody recommend a particular registrar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As documented under [Delegation Record for .IO](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/io.html):

> #### Registry Information
>
> **URL for registration services:** http://www.nic.io/

Comment: Is there any specific registrar you can recommend?

Comment: @CyberKing: What's wrong with registering directly through the NIC, to which I have linked?

Comment: didn't even see that on the site origanaly.

Comment: nic.io's price is currently around $100 while http://gandi.net sell .io domains for $39